# How to make image resize with respect to it's parent region in Apex?

Tags: html, apex

I have an image inside a region (of type static content)

The image is static and is inserted using the code :

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#MyImage.jpg" alt="image">
```

I would like when the parent region is resized, the image resized also.

does anyone know how to achieve that please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#MyImage.jpg" alt="image" style="width: 100%">
```